# CSActiveMQ CPP producer - can one session use multiple queues?

Tags: c++, activemq-cpp

In a question and response here:

[ActiveMQ Producer Multiple Queues One Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537444/activemq-producer-multiple-queues-one-session)

The topic of a single producer sending messages to more them one destination is covered with a solution in Java.

Can the same thing in CPP/CMS be done?

I've tried to replicate that code using cms/activemq API but when I try to send a message to a different queue(destination), I receive error messages stating the producer can only send to the old destination.

Without writing the exact code here is the flow...

- Create new Factory
- Set broker URI
- Create Connection
- Connection start
- Create Session
- Create MessageProducer with a temporary queue
- Create a new queue
- Use session to create message
- MessageProducer send using new queue and message

Comment: Show your code so we can see if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you code has done since you didn't include it but given the minimal input my guess is that you are creating a fixed destination producer by calling `session->createProducer` with some destination (sounds like a temp queue).  This creates a producer married to that destination for life and calling the send methods that take a destination are required to throw.  If you want to pool a producer and send to many different addresses then you need to create it with a `NULL` destination.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim.  This indeed was the case,  The solution is to create a producer with a null destination per your answer above.

Comment: To follow on with this, you can specify a queue/topic for a producer to write to as part of the send arguments, but it seems there is no analog for the consumer/receive or have I just missed it?

Comment: That wouldn't make sense for a consumer, they subscribe to a target address so if you need more subscriptions just create more.  Think the question is now answered, please tag it so others know the solution.